# Date time Comparison in Sql query against CSV File

Tags: c#, sql, .net, csv, odbc

I am using .NET ODBC Connection to query CSV file. I need to compare date time column.

CSV File

```
PID;PNAME;PDATE 
1;A;1/10/2014 9:20:30 AM; 
2;B;2/8/2014 9:20:30 AM; 
3;C;6/29/2014 9:20:30 AM; 
4;D;1/10/2014 9:20:30 AM;

SCHEMA FILE
[Products.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(;)
MaxScanRows=25
CharacterSet=Unicode
```

The below query works fine in SQL Server but it is not working against CSV file.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Products.csv] 
 WHERE CAST(PDATE as datetime) > CAST('1/10/2014 9:20:30 AM' as datetime)
```

I am getting below exception.

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(PDATE as datetime) > CAST('1/10/2014 9:20:30 AM' as datetime)
```

What i am missing in query? Is there any other way to compare date time column?

Comment: delete ending dot "." from your query

Comment: Sorry that is typographical error.